# How can I fully test my SQL tool?

Tags: sql, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I want to build a tool to extract information from queries. How can I test the completeness of my tool, or how can I enumerate all the use cases. Is there a framework or existing examples I can borrow?\

I am using python. I am trying to extract information how a table is being used. Is it used all by itself, or by a join? Which columns are used in join? which columns are used in whereclause. I was sort of trying to build up all the use cases, for example, join two tables, three tables, each column is being used in the selection once, etc.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what you are trying to accomplish?  What language(s) you are using and what is the purpose of the 'tool'?

Comment: I am using python. I am trying to extract information how a table is being used. Is it used all by itself, or by a join? Which columns are used in join? which columns are used whereclause. I was sort of trying to build up all the use cases, for example, join two tables, three tables, each column is being used in the selection once, etc.

Comment: Nitpicking, but: "*extract information from SQLs*" doesn't make sense. "*SQ*" is a _query language_. You can't extract information from a language specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar 'general' question and posted on 
the dba stackexchange (https://dba.stackexchange.com/), here and the code review.  Here and the code review flagged the question as not being qualified for the site's intentions.  However, the people  of the dba stack exchange were helpful.  You may want to post this question to them as well.

Comment: why don'y you link your question here?

Comment: Oh -I am not sure I think one way or the other. there are convincing arguments for and against.  I am just telling you my experience.  That if Stackoverflow flags the question (as they often do). you can try some of the other sites.  I didn't flag your question.  I think we (all of us) should ask general questions .  Makes for a good read.